# How can I check if the core data is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using core data to populate a collection view. Now i want to check if it is empty or not. I want to do additional stuff if it is empty. How can I achieve that?

```
if myJokes.isEmpty == true {
    noFavorites.isHidden = false
  }
```

I have tried to check it likes this but it did not work:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var myJokes : [MyJokes] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getData()
        myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myJokes.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        if myJokes.isEmpty == true {
            noFavorites.isHidden = false
        }
        cell.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        let task = myJokes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = task.favoriteJokes!
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: myCollectionView.frame.width, height: 58)
    }

    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
        myJokes = try context.fetch(MyJokes.fetchRequest())
        } catch {}
    }

    @IBAction func menuBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if menuShowing {
            menuConstraint.constant = -171
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
}
```

Comment: in myJokes what kind of data you get ? like Dictionary , Array etc

Comment: An array of strings

Comment: Did you try `myJokes.count` ?

Comment: Yes that didn't work either

Comment: @Volkan then use like if myJokes.count > 0 {   //here data } else { // no data }